# Is there a way for the content inside a border box to stay on it's place while the border's of the box in the background is changing width?

Tags: css, user-interface, button, icons, border

s there a way for the content inside a border-box to stay in its place while the border of the box in the background is changing width? I'm using radio buttons for a carousel and now I'm decorating it to look like box buttons. Currently, I have a left border turn into a right border (kinds of like drawers opening), but then the icons (the content I placed inside the 'box buttons') get dragged while the borders are moving. I want it to stay in place looking at how it is on hover so I tried using :before for the borders but then it didn't work.

```css
[class^="panel_"] {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 8%;
}

[class^="label_"] {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #c5c8d3;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1.5px solid #c5c8d3;
  border-style: none none none solid;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

[class^="label_"]:hover {
  color: #496676;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #c5c8d3;
}

#button_home:checked~#navigation .label_home,
#button_compilation:checked~#navigation .label_compilation,
#button_about_me:checked~#navigation .label_about_me,
#button_code:checked~#navigation .label_code {
  border-style: solid solid solid none;
  animation: tab 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes tab {
  from {
    width: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #c5c8d3;
    color: #496676;
  }
  to {
    width: 32px;
    color: #496676;
    background-color: #fff2f2;
    border-color: #496676;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="//solrainha.github.io/honeybee/honeybee.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_home" checked />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_compilation" />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_about_me" />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_code" />

  <div id="navigation">
    <label for="button_home" class="label_home"><span class="th th-heart-1-o"></span> </label>
    <label for="button_compilation" class="label_compilation"><span class="th th-folder-3-o"></span></label>
    <label for="button_about_me" class="label_about_me"><span class="th th-eyelash"></span></label>
    <label for="button_code" class="label_code"><span class="th th-code"></span></label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you just want the animation to work on the borders and not not the icon inside it?

Comment: yes, but i think i kind of get it now

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo element:

```css
[class^="label_"] {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #c5c8d3;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
[class^="label_"]::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: #fff2f2;
  border: 1.5px solid #496676;
  border-left:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform:translateX(calc(1.5px - 100%)); /* hide all the element and show only one border */
}

[class^="label_"]:hover {
  color: #496676;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #c5c8d3;
}

#button_home:checked~#navigation .label_home::before,
#button_compilation:checked~#navigation .label_compilation::before,
#button_about_me:checked~#navigation .label_about_me::before,
#button_code:checked~#navigation .label_code::before {
  transform:translateX(0); /* show the element on click */
}
#button_home:checked~#navigation .label_home,
#button_compilation:checked~#navigation .label_compilation,
#button_about_me:checked~#navigation .label_about_me,
#button_code:checked~#navigation .label_code {
  color:#496676;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="//solrainha.github.io/honeybee/honeybee.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_home" checked />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_compilation" />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_about_me" />
  <input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_code" />

  <div id="navigation">
    <label for="button_home" class="label_home"><span class="th th-heart-1-o"></span> </label>
    <label for="button_compilation" class="label_compilation"><span class="th th-folder-3-o"></span></label>
    <label for="button_about_me" class="label_about_me"><span class="th th-eyelash"></span></label>
    <label for="button_code" class="label_code"><span class="th th-code"></span></label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you ^^  im sorry but how calc(1.5px - 100%) works?

Comment: @anonrice the -100% will hide all the element to the left but we need to keep on visible border so we have to add +1.5px thus the result is (1.5px - 100%)